# Keyboard doesnt work after resume from suspend (19.04)

Tags: keyboard, suspend, 19.04, xinput

I have an acer aspire R14 2-in-one convertible laptop. The error I'm encountering is that most times I resume from suspend, the keyboard does not work. I have tried numerous fixes such as disabling rfkill or adding "atkdb.reset" to /etc/default/grub, trying to renable with xinput didnt work either. Because I'm on a 2 in one convertible, I suspect it may have something to do with the driver that disables the keyboard when in tablet mode. I did try running dmesg | grep keyboard and got this output:

```
[    1.104930] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input5
[    1.115661] atkbd serio1: keyboard reset failed on isa0060/serio1
[    2.150305] atkbd serio2: keyboard reset failed on isa0060/serio2
[    3.590299] atkbd serio3: keyboard reset failed on isa0060/serio3
[    5.030300] atkbd serio4: keyboard reset failed on isa0060/serio4
[   71.537335] atkbd serio1: keyboard reset failed on isa0060/serio1
[   72.586254] atkbd serio2: keyboard reset failed on isa0060/serio2
[   74.218248] atkbd serio3: keyboard reset failed on isa0060/serio3
[   75.850117] atkbd serio4: keyboard reset failed on isa0060/serio4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have figured out a solution, as recommended by a friend. Adding `i8042.noaux=1` to grub boot options completely eliminated the issue. Other topics had recommended `atkdb.reset i8042.nomux` which didn't work; in fact, i8042.nomux completely messed up my keyboard.

Comment: Was that only the keyboard not working? Or, also the screen was remaining black? I have a similar problem, but in my case nothing works, even network stays down.

Comment: Only the keyboard.